# Own domain for each category

Tags: wordpress, dns, categories

I'm running an existing Wordpress blog about a single topic with cleary distinguishable subtopics. Those subtopics generate enough interest and content that they could easily be a blog by themselves.

As I'm just running this one blog, each of this subtopics represents a category. For SEO reasons I now would like to run each category on its own domain. For better understanding:

- www.category-a.com displays content of myblog.com/category/category-a/
- www.category-b.com displays content of myblog.com/category/category-b/
- www.category-c.com displays content of myblog.com/category/category-c/
- etc.

The navigation and links within the blog to other posts in different categories should always end up in the correct domain.

Is there any plugin or any different way to accomplish a behaviour like this?

Thanks & Cheers!

Comment: Creating a blog per topic and going wordpress3(MU) is off the table?

Comment: @Brian As the blog already exists I was hoping for a different solution…

Comment: if you're worried about database migration - you'll have this problem anyway: you need to change all post URLs to www.category-a.com, www.category-b.com... depending on the category.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just map the document root of each domain to myblog.com/category/category-a/

Comment: _"The navigation and links within the blog to other posts in different categories should always end up in the correct domain."_

Comment: It should work the other way round. The content of the category should be display under the category-a.com instead of myblog.com.